# Как с помощью метакласса создать сеттер класса в Python?

Tags: python, setter, property, metaclass

Я хочу сделать метакласс, который переделывает методы класса в property и setter. Например, у меня есть такой класс:

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        print("this is property")
        return self._x

    def set_x(self, x: int):
        print("this is setter")
        self._x = x
```

А я хочу, чтобы он работал так:

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        print("this is property")
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x: int):
        print("this is setter")
        self._x = x
```

Пока что я смогла понять, как это можно сделать для property:

```
class PropertyConvert(type):
    def __new__(cls, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
        new_attr = {}
        for name, val in future_class_attr.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                if name.startswith('get_'):
                    new_attr[name[4:]] = property(val)
                if name.startswith('set_'):
                    # ???
            else:
                new_attr[name] = val
        return type.__new__(cls, future_class_name, future_class_parents, new_attr)
```

Но не могу понять, что делать с сеттером.

Answer (score 0):

Функция setter-а передается в функцию property() вторым параметром.